# Is the Service serveo.net safe and private?

Tags: android, payload, wan

I created a reverse tcp payload for android on port 3333. and forwarded it with serveo. But the main Concern is anyone in the world can listen on this port and get the reverse connection. How can i make this connection private so only i can access it ?

Comment: it's an ssh server so just setup an ssh key for authentication although that defeats the point of using serveo in the first place(letting anyone connect)

Comment: can you please explain a bit more. Thanks

Comment: i added an answer @Zibran

Comment: i deleted my answer as it is incorrect - from https://serveo.net/blog/remote-access-to-ssh-servers-using-serveo - When SSH is used properly, using serveo.net doesn't give Serveo access to your server, nor does it expose data to Serveo. Serveo copies encrypted data between your SSH server and client, but has no way of decrypting the data or sending commands to your server. so basically you can use serveo with no problems whatsoever, it is secure and doesn't let users execute commands via ssh(so my answer would be wrong)

Comment: Be carefull though never bind payload to 443 port, anyone can acces it, got my pc infested because of it.

Answer (score 0):

Used serveo and ngrok and stuck with ngrok. I believe them when they say it's safe but I also added additional layers of security to my host machine that issues the SSH, by hardening the SSH config and opening up the minimum ports required in iptables. For example I limited inbound SSH traffic only from my local subnet. I did this because while learning about ngrok, I found on the net (forgot where) that there is a chance someone can determine the IP of the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

Serveo is just using reverse proxy. He can see you from server as ssh client who allowed server to move traffic to local server.
I created my own server using nginx and Amazon ec2 instance, certbot for free ssl.

Comment: using nginx and Amazon ec2 instance is basically just webhosting, isnt it?

Comment: @lendo you can forward local port to ec2 instance , basically using ssh reverse proxy.

https://goteleport.com/blog/ssh-tunneling-explained/